# Using multitouch zoom with image and scroller

Tags: android, ios, image, apache-flex, zooming

How can I add multitouch zoom to my image?

Code of my app:

```
    <s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:Group> 
        <s:Image left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="-11"
                 source="@Embed(source='plans/rera.jpg')"/> 
    </s:Group>        
</s:Scroller>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your Image (in this case "img") and add the following ActionScript code

```
    <s:Image id="img"
             left="0"
             right="0"
             top="0"
             bottom="-11"
             source="@Embed(source='plans/rera.jpg')" />
```

```
        private function addEventListenerImage() : void
        {
            // call this function e.g. onCreationComplete Event
            img.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoomImg);
        }

        private function onZoomImg($event : TransformGestureEvent) : void
        {
            img.scaleX = $event.scaleX;
            img.scaleY = $event.scaleY;
        }
```

Comment: @z5359 Can you please add the following line of code in the addEventListenerImage function and report back:
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
Also, please put a trace in your onZoomImg function to see if the function gets triggered. If it gets triggered, then there will be other factors which prevent the image from scaling.

Comment: I add the  Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE; in the function , how can I put a trace in the onZoomImg fonction ?

Comment: how can I put the trace in Onzoomimg fonction ?

Comment: private function onZoomImg($event : TransformGestureEvent) : void
        {
            trace("onZoomImg") // This is your trace
            img.scaleX = $event.scaleX;
            img.scaleY = $event.scaleY;
        }

Comment: I added the track but it does not change anything, here is a screenshot of my code [link](http://1drv.ms/1g2UH8P)

Comment: Looks like you don't call the function "addEventListenerImage". Try adding the following:<s:View onCreationComplete="addEventListenerImage(event)" [...]

Comment: I add what you, but it does not zoom, if you want to test go [link](http://1drv.ms/1ij6gNk) for android

Comment: I add what you say, but it does not zoom, look this [link](http://youtu.be/s0uNx4gXMjw)  @Jan

Comment: Please post your current source code as text somewhere so I can have a look. In the source code of the screenshot you do not call the function "addEventListenerImage" - did you fix that like I suggested earlier?

Comment: Please add the following to the addEventListener function and post your output here:  
    var supportedGesturesVar : Vector.<String> = Multitouch.supportedGestures;

    trace("\n");
    for (var i : int = 0; i < supportedGesturesVar.length; ++i)
    {
     trace("Supported gesture: " + supportedGesturesVar[i])
    }

    trace("Number of Touchpoints: " + Multitouch.maxTouchPoints);
    trace("\n");

Comment: If there are no traces the function does not get called. It looks like "s:View" does not support the event listener onCreationComplete. Have a look here: http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html.  Change the code to something like <s:View [..] viewActivate="addEventListenerImage()". Wondering though, why you did no get any compiletime errors after adding the creationComplete event listener

Comment: I change the call of the fonction and I get this error when I launch the app [link](http://1drv.ms/1iXQPKJ)

Comment: Again, please show your code with line numbers. Did you make sure to import Multitouch, MultitouchInputMode and TransformGestureEvent?

Comment: Add the traces about Multitouch support to your main class and check if multitouch is supported at all. Or create a new simple example project, add an image and add the code from above to see if it works at all.

Comment: Hy , I create a new sample project and the project is here [link](http://1drv.ms/1ovVgxM)

Comment: If you call the function "addEventListenerImage" onCreationComplete you will see that it actually works. Also, change the according lines to the following "img.scaleX *= $event.scaleX; img.scaleY *= $event.scaleY;". Next step you should read about how layouts and element aligment works